# how to use msgclt() API appropreatly?

Tags: operating-system

I am writing two processes and they are communicating using a FIFO. And at the end I have deleted the FIFO. But next time when I am running the application, it throws a core dump. Because it's processing some junk packets. I think that FIFO is not getting deleted.
      I am using this API to delete it. 
msgctl(consoleFifo,IPC_RMID,NULL);

Is there anything more I have to do to get it deleted ??

Thanks.